# Firestore deep query using a cloud function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I am incredibly new with javascript and I do not entirely understand promises. For simple operations like read or write, I understand that a promise is needed before the code can continue, but I am not entirely sure how to deal with multiple promises at once, specifically after calling .get().

My goal is to query documents quite deep within my Firestore db, and the names of documents in subcollections higher up are not known to me, as they are created by the users. Each user will have places and these places will have guests, and my function intends to search through the guests and select them according to a field value. My code so far is this. Is there a better way?

```
async function getGuests() {
  var results = [];
  var users = await db.collection('users').get();
  users.forEach(async function(doc) {
    var places = await doc.collection('places').get();
    places.forEach(async function(doc2) {
      var guests = await doc2.collection('guests').where(...).get();
      return results.concat(guests);
    });
  return results;
  });
  
  return results;
}
```

hierarchy looks like:

```
users/{userID}/places/{place_name}/guests/{guest}
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?  I'm not clear why you need to do three queries.  Is it not sufficient to just query the guests subcollection?  Please edit the question to explain more clearly the data you're working with and your end goal.

Comment: added. basically I need to query guests according to a field, and while the structure will always be the same, I won't know the names of the documents leading to those guests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to do a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) instead.  What you're doing right now is massively inefficient if you just want to make a query among all subcollections called "guests".

```
const querySnapshot = await db.collectionGroup('guests').get();
// iterate queryShapshot to get document contents
```

Comment: Thanks, was not aware of this. Exactly what I needed